# How to set RpcClientAccessServer for a Exchange 2010 mailbox database to a load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, exchange-2010

I have 2 Exchange 2010 servers each with a Mailbox Database. I have also setup a Hardware Load Balancer (KEMP LoadMaster 2200 to be precise) to load balance the CAS role access.

My HLB has an IP of 192.168.1.100. I've setup the DNS A record for mail.mydomain.com to point to 192.168.1.100. However when I try to set the RpcClientAccessServer on a mailbox database using

```
Set-MailboxDatabase "My Mailbox Database" -RpcClientAccessServer mail.mydomain.com
```

I get an error saying

```
Exchange server "mail.mydomain.com" was not found. Please make sure you have typed it correctly.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 4082394C
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the command Get-ClientAccessArray return?

Comment: Yup that was the problem. Hadn't setup a CAS array for my HLB's DNS A record. Thanks Tatas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that want the answer.  Use the commandlet New-ClientCasArray to create your FQDN for the CAS array.  Then use Get-MailboxDatabase | Set-MailboxDatabase -RPCClientAccessServer “FQDN” to set all your existing mailbox databases (if you have already created some) to use the new CAS array.